# Heatmap sorted by Sample group then clustered within groups in R

Tags: r, plot, heatmap

Basically I want to create a heatmap with columns subdivided into two groups then resorted with dendograms in the groups so that we can identify which genes are up and downregulated for each.

I'm working with RNA HT12 microarray data for patient samples with roughly n>150 per group.  And while I'm achieving significant differential expression between the groups, my heatmaps are not separating into distinct case/control groups when using the default dendogram.  An example of the code I used is below.  {I tried to add the heatmap but I don't have the points yet}

```
#Code for Heatmap
library(gplots) 
selected <- p.adjust(fit$p.value[, 2], "fdr") <0.005
esetSel <- HT_H_N[selected, ]
color.map <- function(STAT) { if (STAT=="case") "#00FF00" else "#0000FF" }
patientcolors <- unlist(lapply(esetSel$STAT, color.map))
heatmap(exprs(esetSel),ColSideColors=patientcolors)
```

At first I thought that the extent of differential expression between the groups was low but when I generate a heatmap for each group individually, the case group looks to have lower expression than controls.

So I would like to break my comparisons into groups and then sorted by clustering.  At first I entertained performing hclustering on each group then creating a new phenodata field with the clustering order for each group in it.  Then using that field to reorder my columns.

Is there a simpler way to achieve this?

Comment: After doing a bit more searching, I think what I want to do is constrained clustering for my samples.  I found the 'rioja' package (http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rioja/index.html) but I'm not sure if chclust within it will perform exactly what I'm looking for.